# How can I fix the position of tables formatted with `renewenvironment{table}`?

Tags: tables, floats, environments

I've used `renewenvironment{table}` to make all my table rules green. I also want to fix the position of some of them, using the option `H` of `float` package, for instance. I've tried a solution like the one showed below but I get an error. If I comment out  `\restylefloat{table}`, I get just a `[H]` written next to the table (*vide* https://www.overleaf.com/read/jvxrhvhqmmgh).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\restylefloat{table}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}
     {\@float{table}\taburulecolor{green}\arrayrulecolor{green}     }
     {\end@float}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a caption.}
    \label{tab:atable}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
        \hline
        4 & 5 & 6 \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances you'd just need to do the settings first and then call `\@float{table}`. But here you're using `\restylefloat`, which changes the definition of `\table` to something different than `\@float{table}` like in the kernel definition.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\restylefloat{table}

\makeatletter
\let\float@table\table % must be after \restylefloat{table}
\renewenvironment{table}
  {\taburulecolor{green}\arrayrulecolor{green}\float@table}
  {\end@float}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a caption.}
    \label{tab:atable}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
        \hline
        4 & 5 & 6 \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't call `colortbl`, but rather pass the the `table` option to `xcolor`.