# How can I have an additional "source'' caption in a table redefined with `renewenvironment`?

Tags: captions, environments, source

I had tables working well with a regular caption above and source information below each of them:

[image: Figure with caption and source.]

After implementing a solution given in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/485538/91816, the captions disappeared.

[image: Figure without regular caption.]

I think the captions were replaced by the ones defined by the source command.

See the MWE below (https://www.overleaf.com/read/bryfbdpbfcww).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\usepackage{caption}

% TABLE CONFIGURATION
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\makeatletter
\let\float@table\table % must be after \restylefloat{table}
\renewenvironment{table}
     {\taburulecolor{green}\arrayrulecolor{green}\float@table}
 {\end@float}
\makeatother
% TABLE CONFIGURATION

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\captionsetup{singlelinecheck=false,justification=justified}\caption*{\footnotesize \noindent Source: {#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]

    \centering
    \caption{This is a caption.}
    \label{tab:atable}

    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 \tabularnewline
        \hline
        4 & 5 & 6 \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \source{This is the source.}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It only works if I comment out the code between the lines with `% TABLE CONFIGURATION`.

In my real document, it is worse than that, because not even the sources appear. I guess some other package such as `newfloat` is causing other problems.

Comment: The `plaintop` style works hard to redefine everything in order to catch a caption after the table to go at the top and fails when there are two captions in the same `table` environment, which is allowed in standard LaTeX; only the second caption appears.

Comment: Whenever I see someone trying to implement some peculiar `ABNT` rule, I ask if they've taken a look at the class designed to take care of it -- or at least the solutions offered therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the `plaintop` style. When you have two captions in the same `table` environments, which is allowed by LaTeX, restyled floats using `plaintop` just print the second caption and forget the first one.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering

\caption{First caption}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Second caption}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
a & b \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Solution: don't `\restylefloat{table}` and type captions where they belong.